# How to show subdivisions on one viewport only?

Tags: 3d-view

I was wondering if it's possible to have the subdivisions to show only on one viewport, so I can have a quick preview on my second viewport while editing the raw low poly geometry, something like that:

[image]

Comment: This would be very handy.. if you do it with an Alt-D (unmodified) instance, unfortunately, the modified instance doesn't update until you've flipped in and out of Object Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'kind of' get close by disabling overlays in one viewport

Then you have one viewport with vertices, and second one showing only the final result.

[image]

Comment: That would still leave the subdivided mesh underneath the raw quads and it’s very confusing to look at